# python doesn't see package installed by brew

Tags: macos, homebrew, python

I have Python installed with brew and I cannot import a fontTools package even though it is installed in brew. I only have this one Python version on my computer. Any ideas why it is not linked? I am using ARM macbook with Sonoma macos.

```
$ python3.12
Python 3.12.2 (main, Feb  6 2024, 20:19:44) [Clang 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import fontTools
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fontTools'
>>> exit()
$ brew install fontTools
Warning: fonttools 4.50.0 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 4.50.0, run:
  brew reinstall fonttools
```

Comment: You've done `which python3.12`, just to check? According to HomeBrew docs, you should use `pip3` to install libraries, not `brew install`. https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python#:~:text=It%20is%20possible%20to%20install,with%20pip%20inside%20a%20virtualenv.

Comment: Yes: '''$ which python3.12
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3.12"

Comment: The problem is pip wants me to do it with brew: '''$ pip3.12  install fontTools
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try brew install
    xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.

    If you wish to install a non-brew-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip.

...
'''

Answer (score 1):

That's not the name of the importable library.

There is complete documentation available [here](https://fonttools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), which describes the available libraries.

> The main library you will want to access when using fontTools for font
> engineering is likely to be fontTools.ttLib.ttFont, which is the
> module for handling TrueType/OpenType fonts. However, there are many
> other libraries in the fontTools suite.

Example:

```
$ python3 -m venv test                                                                                                             
$ cd test                                                                                                               
$ . bin/activate                                                                                                        
(test) $ pip3 install fontTools                                                                                         
Collecting fontTools                                                                                                    
  Downloading fonttools-4.50.0-cp311-cp311-macosx_10_9_universal2.whl.metadata (159 kB)                                 
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 159.4/159.4 kB 3.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00                                       
Downloading fonttools-4.50.0-cp311-cp311-macosx_10_9_universal2.whl (2.8 MB)                                            
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.8/2.8 MB 24.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00                                            
Installing collected packages: fontTools                                                                                
Successfully installed fontTools-4.50.0                                                                                 
$ python3                                                                                                               
Python 3.11.8 (main, Feb 10 2024, 20:48:19) [Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)] on darwin                             
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.                                                  
>>> import fontTools.ttLib.ttFont                                                                                       
>>> exit()                                                                                                              
(test) $
```

Reading the [formula](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/fonttools#default), it looks like all it sets up is for the command line executables that are part of `fonttools` to work, it does not add anything to `site-packages`.  Homebrew Python 3.12+ follows PEP 668.  So you are going to need to instantiate a virtualenv and then install the package there with `pip3`, as I showed.

(I edited my example to change my alias invocation for creating the venv to the actual command line to use)

Comment: Pip does not want to install it for me, it want me to do it with brew and then brew says it's already there:                                                                            
                                                                                                               
'$ pip3.12 install fonttools
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try brew install
    xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
'

Comment: OK, now I understand, so the issue is this new PEP 668 stuff. The way I overcame it is by adding "--break-system-packages" flag for pip and it worked. The other would be to instantiate a virtualenv, as you mentioned.